# Amarok does not start

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, amarok

I run Kubuntu 18.04 for about 1 year now.

2 months ago, Amarok suddenly stopped working. Every time I try starting it, I get this windows:
[image: Bug window]

If I try starting it form command line, I get this error messages:

```
user@computer:~$ amarok
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
KCrash: Application 'amarok' crashing...
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/drkonqi from kdeinit
KCrash: Connect sock_file=/home/flocon/.kde/socket-flocon-Aspire-E5-576G/kdeinit4__0
unnamed app(8164): Communication problem with  "amarok" , it probably crashed. 
Error message was:  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply" : " "Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying" " 

user@computer:~$ 2019-10-13 11:43:36 0x7ff492ffd700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140688414988032 in file fil0fil.cc line 5799
InnoDB: Failing assertion: req_type.is_dblwr_recover() || err == DB_SUCCESS
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
Unable to start Dr. Konqi
Not forwarding the crash to Apport.
```

I Initially suspected that something was wrong with an update so I just waited. Of course I also tried to reinstall Amarok, to `remove --purge` it, but when it is back it always falls again into this bug.

A quick search on the Web did not allow me to find other people in the same situation.

Would you have an idea of what I could do to make Amarok work?

**Edit**: addition of Developper info tab
[image]

Comment: InnoDB crash seems from Dr. Konqi debug tool not from Amarok itself. Could you copy Developer info tab to the question from the message window for KDE crash handler. You may also backup Amarok profile in `/home/flocon/.kde/..` probably and delete local profile, try restart Amarok after that. It is convenient to raise a bug report if it is still failing after deleting profile and your system is updated.

Comment: Information added... but the deletion of my Amarok profile in .kde/share/apps allowed Amarok to restart :) So thank you @user.dz! Please feel free to copy your comment in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB crash seems from Dr. Konqi debug tool not from Amarok itself. Developer info tab from KDE crash handler does show any.

1. Backup Amarok profile in `~/.kde/share/apps/..` (If you have library data that you want to keep) and delete local profile
2. Try restart Amarok after that.

It is convenient to raise a bug report if it is still failing after deleting profile and your system is updated.